# Visual Studio remote test - Cannot connect to a test controller on a virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I have Test controller and Test agent installed on a virtual machine VM1. Test agent is shown is Online. I'm trying to run CodedUI tests remotely from my machine. But every time I go to Test -> Manage Test Controllers... in VS2010 it hangs. The same effect when I try to run any test remotely.

Both machines are in the same domain, on my machine i'm using domain admin user, on VM local admin.

I've got these 2 errors in Event Viewer:

1. > The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be
   >   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
   >   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
   >   or repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated
   >   on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the
   >   event. The following information was included with the event:
   >
   > **(devenv.exe, PID 7732, Thread 1) IdleProcessorManager.DoWork - Job
   >   threw: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:
   >   '7c58e17b-57a5-e486-31cc-aca08ec38d23'**  Key being added:
   >   '7c58e17b-57a5-e486-31cc-aca08ec38d23' at    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.Xml.XmlPersistence.LoadHashtable[K,V](XmlElement
   >   element, String location, String keyLocation, String valueLocation,
   >   XmlTestStoreParameters parameters)    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestListCategory.Load(XmlElement
   >   element, XmlTestStoreParameters parameters)    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.Xml.XmlFilePersistence.LoadTestList(String
   >   fileName)    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.Tmi.LoadCategories(String
   >   location, TestListCategoryConflictHandler idVetoingHandler,
   >   TestListCategoryConflictHandler nameVetoingHandler)    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.Tmi.LoadCategories(String
   >   location)    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.SolutionIntegrationManager.LoadCategoriesIntoTmi(String
   >   filename)    at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.SolutionIntegrationManager.d__83.MoveNext()
   >   at
   >   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.IdleProcessorManager.DoWork()
2. > The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
   >   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
   >   or repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated
   >   on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the
   >   event. The following information was included with the event:
   >
   > (devenv.exe, PID 7732, Thread 65) **Timed out waiting for controller
   >   connect**

Comment: Is Visual Studio reporting an error? It seems like visual studio cannot find the controller. Maybe the controller service is not running or it is not configured to run through VS but through MTM. Did you use this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400223.aspx)?

Comment: @Schaliasos: yes, I did all the steps mentioned in this walkthrough. I did not anything specific to MTM, so I guess it should be ok for VS. or there are some specific steps for VS?

Comment: @Schaliasos: And yes, it's VS who throws this exceptions (devenv.exe). The controller seems to be running, at least the agent says that it's online.

Comment: Seems like this is a [known issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/68be4844-8ea4-40e4-a02e-a92004680338/). It is also [added a bug in Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543848/vsttexecution-failure) but unfortunately it is closed as Not Reproducible.

Comment: Sorry but that seems like a different issue. At least the exceptions they're getting are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/4e8445e6-5c35-4c33-820e-0c334046631b?prof=required

Running Visual Studio in Safe mode solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by installing [update 2 of Visual Studio](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/msdnsandbox/thread/7195f6fc-58aa-454e-a96e-ea442f6590e6).

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar exception (see bellow).

There was a run setting configured and used from my project solution under

"Visual Studio/Test/Configure Run Settings/"

So I unchecked and it was working again...

Under Configure Run Settings, now I have :
a "Checked Auto Detect runsettings Files"
and the "Select Solution Wide runsettings File entry"
and the unchecked "project.testsettings" file.

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

(testhost.x86.exe, PID 10320, Thread 3) TestTypes\{7a24f8ff-85da-d664-ef44-83ff4743dae6} could not be loaded because the TIP could not be instantiated for the following reason(s): An item with the same key has already been added.

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table
```